# Getting selected Items from Jlist

Tags: java, swing

I have seen many posts & tried different ways to solve this problem but still I dont get my list of selected items. Here's the code which I use.

```
public List<String> getSelectedDeviceList()
    {
        return list;
    }
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public JLogicDesign(Frame frame, List<String> listDevices) {

        super();
        setTitle("Device Names");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 331, 316);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        jlistModel = new DefaultListModel(); 
        for(String s: listDevices)
        {
            jlistModel.addElement(s);
        }

        final JList jlist = new JList(jlistModel);
        jlist.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


        btnOk = new JButton("OK");      
        btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {                   

                    list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Object[] values = jlist.getSelectedValues();
                    for(Object o: values)
                    {
                        list.add(o.toString());
                    }               
                dispose();
            }
        });
```

The JList is being properly populated. When I try to get the selected Items, I get a NPE.

This is another class where I'm calling the above class

```
JLogicDesign jld = new JLogicDesign(f,listOfDevices);           

            devices = new ArrayList<String>();
            devices = jld.getSelectedDeviceList();
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Just a quick comment, [JList.getSelectedValues()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValues%28%29) is deprecated since java 1.7. You should use [JList.getSelectedValuesList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList%28%29) instead.

Comment: My installed java version is 1.6.

Comment: Which is the line you are getting the exception at?

Comment: The code is not complete, so it is hard to guess what the problem is. Which exact line is "this line"?

Comment: @Dan : there's another class which is calling the selected List of items. 
JLogicDesign jld = new JLogicDesign(f,listOfDevices);           

            devices = new ArrayList<String>();
            devices = jld.getSelectedDeviceList(); <-- here it gives me an NPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get NPE at this line:

```
JLogicDesign jld = new JLogicDesign(f,listOfDevices);
devices = new ArrayList<String>();
devices = jld.getSelectedDeviceList(); // NPE here
```

Because `list` variable in `JLogicDesign` is only initialized when `btnOk` is pressed. So the pointed line is executed before this button is pressed and that's why it throws NPE.

To avoid NPE you shoud initialize `list` in `JLogicDesign`. However it doesn't solve the problem. You wont get NPE but you'll get an empty list. This is because `JLogicDesign` is not modal and even if these sentences are being executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) `jld.getSelectedDeviceList()` will return the `list` *before* `btnOk` is pressed.

If you need the selected devices *before* continue then consider use a modal `JDialog`.

Comment: Oh ok. So what should be done to make that particular line execute after the OK button is pressed ?

Comment: @sarath you have to wait until the GUI is disposed before you try to access the device list. Look into the event dispatch thread.

Comment: @dic19 : Update - I actually initialised the list before the OK button is pressed. But this time as expected I dont get a NPE but instead an empty list which is fair, but i get an empty list even if some items are being selected?

Comment: @dic19 : Thanks a bunch. Realised what was missing. I added a boolean modal to the constructor of JLogicDesign & made super(frame,true). It worked now perfectly. Could you please give me a link to understand more about "modal" & its role.

Comment: @sarath and I've just realized that `JLogicDesign` extends from `JDialog` :P I thought (don't know why) it extends from `JFrame` but I was wrong. Anyway, here some interest links: [An Overview of Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#overview) and [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html). The last one is not so straight forward so take it easy and read it carefully.